# How can i process huge javascript array (array of 20 mil coordinates) in browser side efficiently?

Tags: javascript, arrays, performance, google-chrome, d3.js

here's my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <title>d3 Practice</title>
</head>

<body>
<script src="./vislibs/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="test" width="1024" height="768" style="border: 1px solid black;"></canvas>
<script>
function generate_data(size){
    var randomX = d3.random.normal(width/2 , 80),
        randomY = d3.random.normal(height/2, 80);

    var data = d3.range(size).map(function() {
      return [
        randomX(),
        randomY()
      ];
    });
    return data
}
function main() {
    var canvasEl = d3.select('#test').node();

    // get 2d context to draw on
    var ctx = canvasEl.getContext('2d');
        width = canvasEl.width
    height = canvasEl.height
    data=generate_data(20000000)
    alert("data generated")
    // set fill color of context
    var x = 0
    ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
    batch_size = 10000

    debugger // Cannot step into requestAnimationFrame(draw_loop) at all , freezing eternity
    draw_loop = function () {
        if (x<=data.length-1) {
            for (i in d3.range(0,batch_size)){

                    //console.log(x)
                    ctx.fillRect(data[x][0], data[x][1], 2, 2);
                    x = x+1

            }

            setTimeout(draw_loop,100);
        }
    }

    requestAnimationFrame(draw_loop)
    //alert("done reqanim")
}
main()
//init()

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

This will freeze browser after `generate_data(20000000)` is generated, without even going to  `requestAnimationFrame(draw_loop)` . I tested without `requestAnimationFrame` or `setTimeout` and rendering everything at once but works fine  but it freeze the browser for a bit. 
Offloading to server seems to be a good solution but i would like to know why pausing (setTimeout and requestAnimiationFrame) cause browser to freeze for infinity instead of giving control to the browser.

Tested on linux , Chromium Version 26.0.1410.43 (189671).

Memory usage of browser is about 1.4 GB just one tab of that script opening after `generate_data(20000000)` is done , but i have 6 GB of memory free on my laptop. So is there any efficient way to process it? (without causing Unresponsive or Freezing Infinitely)

EDIT:

here is working JSFiddle
[2 mil rectangles](http://jsfiddle.net/BumFs/)

This will freeze your browser.
[20 mil rectangles](http://jsfiddle.net/cWLy7/)

Without setTimeout or requestAnimationFrame , this will cause 1-2 unresponsive but can render well to the end without freezing.
[20 mil rectangles without pausing functions](http://jsfiddle.net/F4bzt/2/)

Proof of concept , no rendering code , data is generated you will see alert box after data generation , but browser is frozen as soon as it hit requestAnimationFrame. (20 mil points) [will freeze browser](http://jsfiddle.net/xG4VC/6/) ,

```
function generate_data(size){
    var randomX = d3.random.normal(width/2 , 80),
        randomY = d3.random.normal(height/2, 80);

    var data = d3.range(size).map(function() {
      return [
        randomX(),
        randomY()
      ];
    });
    return data
}
function main() {
    var canvasEl = d3.select('#test').node();

    // get 2d context to draw on (the "bitmap" mentioned earlier)
    var ctx = canvasEl.getContext('2d');
        width = canvasEl.width
    height = canvasEl.height
    data=generate_data(20000000)
    alert("data generated")
    // set fill color of context
    var x = 0
    ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
    batch_size = 10000

    //debugger // Cannot step into requestAnimationFrame(draw_loop) at all , freezing eternity
    draw_loop = function () {
        if (x<=data.length-1) {
            nada=""
            x=x+batch_size
            setTimeout(draw_loop,100);
        }
    }

    requestAnimationFrame(draw_loop)
    alert("done reqanim")
}
main()
```

[2 mil points version , without rendering code , that works](http://jsfiddle.net/xG4VC/5/)

Comment: It's not the `setTimeout`/`requestAnimationFrame` which is freezing your browser, but just the 60mil function calls in a single loop?

Comment: do you want that effect that the graphic builds itself up slowly? or is it just a byproduct?

Comment: @Bergi try this : http://jsfiddle.net/F4bzt/2/ it is done without using a single setTimeout or requestAnimationFrame and it works till the end.So we can say the problem is from pausing the js thread under heavy load, as explained by StMotorSpark

Comment: @basilikum it is building up slowly to give back control to browser. it is byproduct but looks good tho :)

Comment: @V3ss0n maybe you could try then to precalculate an image data array, that you can pass to `ctx.putImageData`. Could be more efficient since you wouldn't need to draw every single pixel by itself and you also wouldn't need to draw a pixel that is already there.

Comment: @basilikum Very interesting! i will check that out, i am new to canvas and testing performance . But still the freeze is not caused by canvas rendering at all. I have tested by removing all the rendering code and just puting setTimeOut(dummy_func,100) and it freeze after  `generate_data(20000000)` as soon at it hit setTimeout ( soon after thread is paused 100 ms).

Comment: V3ss0n, @basilikum's suggestion is dead on. This should be the correct answer. I'm surprised you're still getting freezing even without any rendering. I just tested myself and saw no freezing. Can you post another jsfiddle?

Comment: @V3ss0n was too eager to experiment with this. created a fiddle and posted an answer :)

Comment: Yes i will add another jsfiddle without any rendering code.

Comment: Why would you ever want to show a user 20 million rectangles?  What real world problem are you actually trying to solve?

Comment: test for K-mean visualization of >20 million documents as a scatterplot. On real use case we will have kmean visualization of 20mil + documents for digital forensics, user will be able to create a selection box of documents near centroids. In-house application , not for internet site, but web-based.

Comment: @Ash , i have added proof of concept

Comment: Altough i got the desired performance from basilikum's code , i still want to understand why it do freeze .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of trying to create threads and artificial breaks you could speed up your code by precalculation an image data array. You code so far has two flaws:

1. You draw every single pixel individualy
2. You redraw pixels that are already there

Because of the sheer number of data points, those two flaws can add up really quickly. When you run your original fiddle you see that after just a second, the picture doesn't change anymore but you are still drawing pixels over the same area for maybe 20 further seconds. So here is an example of how can do it with the `putImageData()` function:

```
function createPictureArray() {
    var res, i, max_i;
    var canvasEl = d3.select('#test').node();
    var ctx = canvasEl.getContext('2d');
    var data;

    res = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, width, height);
    data = res.data;
    for (i = 0, max_i = data.length; i < max_i; i++) {
        data[i] = 255;
    }
    return res;
}

function generateData(size) {
    var i, x, y, s, res, data, randomX, randomY;

    randomX = d3.random.normal(width/2 , 80);
    randomY = d3.random.normal(height/2, 80);    

    res = createPictureArray();
    data = res.data;
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {

        x = parseInt(randomX());
        y = parseInt(randomY());
        s = 4 * y * width + 4 * x;
        if (data.length > s && data[s + 1] !== 0) {
            data[s + 1] = 0;
            data[s + 2] = 0;
        }
    }
    return res;
}

function main() {
    var canvasEl = d3.select('#test').node();
    var ctx = canvasEl.getContext('2d');
    width = canvasEl.width;
    height = canvasEl.height;
    data = generateData(2000000);
    ctx.putImageData(data, 0, 0);

}
main()
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/BumFs/2/)

This example creates 2 million data points but feel free to increase it to 20 million. On my machine it took about 7 seconds. So there is still room for optimization but at least I didn't experienced severe freezing.

What happens is that you create your random numbers one after the other and for each number pair you calculate the correct pixel inside the image data array and you set that pixel to red if it has not already been set red.

Comment: Incredible! 200 mil points rendered in 17 secs! wow! Thanks alot, Your code is most efficient! Altough this do not answer the problem of js thread freezing as soon as setTimeout is entered , this performance is enough for many uses cases for me. Amazing!

Comment: @V3ss0n Thanks a lot. I'm glad it helped you! Btw the bottleneck of this whole calculation seems to be the calculations of the random numbers with d3.js. If you want it to run faster maybe you could find an even faster library or try to implement a fast algorithm by yourself (but actually I suspect d3.js to quite fast already). Also,  it seems to run quite a bit faster if you replace `parseInt` with `Math.round` in my code.

Comment: Hey @basilikum i am loving ImageData arrays now , only i want some library to make image data array easier. do you any helper? All i see is Color Mainipulation libraries , not helper libs that make it easy . I want for example Easy drawing and locating of circles,squares with color (something that provide just geometries that make it easier to put it under imagedata array)

Comment: @V3ss0n I'm sorry, I'm not really familiar with librarys or frameworks for stuff like that. But I now there is [Raphael](http://raphaeljs.com/) and [Kineticjs](http://kineticjs.com/). I don't know if those are using image data arrays in their code but you could try them out anyway and see how they perform. Maybe they have some sort of buffer or grouping functionality, that let you draw multiple shapes at once or something like that. But I can only guess...

Comment: Yes i tried them already before i going raw canvas.They are very slow , they do not use imageData array , they emulate vector graphics instead. The only library i found that draws using imagedata arrays is called TinyC5 unfortunately it is unmaintained. I am now enjoying ImageData and trying to make shapes (rect,circles) using it. Let me know if there generic algorithm so i can do Shapes using it eficiently.

Answer (score 3):

Javascript is a single threaded system. Functions that essentially create a callback like setTimeout will still kill a single threaded system.

Edit:

As per the comments, there are some creative ways to give the single thread Javascript the illusion of executing large logic functions asynchronously, thus freeing up the process for executing things like click handlers.

@V3ss0n depending on where in your code the process freeze occurs you have a couple of options as follows:

1) Process freezes during creation of the array:
Loading 20 mil items into an array could take a while, and I would recommend not doing this. There is more than 1 way to approach this, but I would move as much heavy looping logic as I can outside of javascript and possibly to a web-service. This has it's own challenges such as attempting to send 20 mil items back to the client, that is a bad idea. But if you can split it up into manageable groups of coordinates (20-100 max) and then make multiple web service calls as needed (using something like JQuery Ajax method http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) then all that your javascript has to worry about is appending the items. That will stream data to you over a period of time, so don't expect it to be instant, but should not freeze the browser if it is having difficulties looping through the coordinate creation function 20 mil time.

2) Process freezes during rendering of each individual point:
The fix for this is a little more creative and can also be used for the above process if you do not want to use web services. First look at the following code:

```
    var renderingCounter = 0;
var asyncTimer = null; // keep the render timer global to prevent duplicate renders from being run

function StartRender(){
    // test if existing async render is running
    if(asyncTimer != null){
        // existing async timer, clear the timer and clear the canvas
        clearInterval(asyncTimer);
        renderingCounter = 0;

        // code for clearing the canvas ..
    };

    // create interval object
    var asyncTimer = setInterval(function (){
        // at the begining of each start render, test if all points have been rendered
        if(renderingCounter >= pointArray.length){
            // kill the asynctimer
            clearInterval(asyncTimer);
            asyncTimer = null;
            renderingCounter = 0; // reset the counter
            return;
        };

        while(renderingCounter < 100){ // only draw 100 items
            if(renderingCounter >= pointArray.length){ // make sure you are not out of array bounds
                return;
            };

            // execute display code for that point
        }; // loop
    }, 40);
}
```

The above code splits up the rendering process into 100 point groups. Upon completion of a group it pauses for 40 milliseconds, this should free up enough time on the main thread to allow execution for other items to continues (such as UI). the global variable renderingCounter will keep the current progress through the array. The code also has checks for current running rendering timers if the function gets re-called during rendering (in the example it kills the current rendering and resets it). If the rendering timer still causes hangs, you can increase the pause interval.

Those two methods of approaching asynchronous execution should provide enough flexibility to allow rendering or data reading from server side web services (should you ever go that direction) while still keeping a fluid ui

Comment: Ah thanks. so how can i avoid that? Also added some tests as jsfiddle.

Comment: There are some creative tricks you can do to give the illusion that your javascript is executing asynchronously that also frees up the thread for execution by other javascript functions. I will edit my original answer with the details.

Comment: Awesome, i am waiting for that.

Comment: Just finished the edits. Let me know if anything is not clear or if you have any questions. :)

Comment: Thanks , i am going to test and give you feedback, also a jsFiddle.

Comment: Awesome, look forward to hearing how it works for you. So far it has worked pretty well for me in various applications.

Answer (score 1):

Both JavaScript and UI updates such as redraws and reflows run in a single "browser UI thread". The browser UI thread works on a queuing system where tasks are kept until the process is idle. Once idle, the next task in the queue is retrieved and executed.

Techniques like setTimeout() and requestAnimationFrame defer execution of your task and allow some breathing space for the UI to update, but when those tasks are eventually run, it's still one at a time, not concurrently. Thus any such task will always block the execution of any other.

HTML5 introduces [web workers](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-workers/current-work/), which allow you to pass Javascript to a separate thread, where it is executed concurrently with the UI thread. The Javascript you execute within a web worker is isolated from the UI thread, and you cannot make any updates to the UI from the web worker. However a web worker would be ideal for something like your generate_data() function.

Here's a great [web worker tutorial](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/workers/basics/) and here's a [browser compatibility matrix](http://caniuse.com/webworkers).

Comment: I am new to webworker and many browser still not supporting it well right? I will look into it too, but i afraid it breaks browser compatibility.

Comment: Yes web worker compatibility is still quite new, and IE in particular hasn't supported it until very recently. I added a compatibility matrix to my answer. You can check for compatibility and only use a web worker if available, and if not available pass the work to a web service as suggested elsewhere.